# How to add Sound Effects with Kotlin in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, soundeffect

How do you program sound effects in kotlin android Looked all over Yt and there all in Java

Comment: Copy the java code and press ctrl + shift + alt + k (Windows), cmd + shift + alt + k (Mac) in android studio and it will convert your java to Kotlin

Comment: What do you mean by "add sound effects"?

Answer (score 1):

Add/Import your sound effect file to your project and use MediaPlayer like this one

private var BgMusic:MediaPlayer? = null

```
fun playBgMusic(){
    BgMusic = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.gamebgmusic)
    BgMusic?.setOnPreparedListener{
        BgMusic?.start()
        musicPlaying = true
    }
    BgMusic?.setOnCompletionListener {
        BgMusic?.start()
    }
}

fun pauseBgMusic(){
    BgMusic!!.pause()
}

fun resumeBgMusic(){
    BgMusic!!.start()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add your sound effect file into your 'resources' folder in your app project, then call it from whichever activity or fragment you would like to execute it in with SoundPool, a public class that enables you to load the audio resource into memory and play it!

I link you here the SoundPool [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool) as well as a [blogpost](https://o7planning.org/en/10523/playing-sound-effects-in-android-with-soundpool) that shows it in action.

Here's also a Kotlin [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-play-sound-using-soundpool-in-kotlin) article.